# errorjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am sending Base64 encoded String via Header with using Retrofit,I got success mesages from services but I got errror in `response.body`

> error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

how can I get `JsonObject` as a correctly without changing Server `JsonObject` format

`RetroClient` Class

```
public static Retrofit getClientFile(String url) {

    String BaseUrl = url + "/";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build();
}
```

`RestInterface` Class

```
public interface RestInterface {

    @GET(".")
    Call<FileResult> doGetFile(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader);
}
```

`DownloadFile` Class

```
public static void downloadFile(String headerData){

    RestInterface restInterface = RetroClient.getClientFile(urlList.get(0)).create(RestInterface.class);
    Call<FileResult> call = restInterface.doGetFile(headerData);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<FileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FileResult> call, Response<FileResult> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d("Downloading FileResult:","" + response.body());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FileResult> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("TAG", "error" + t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

`FileResult` class

```
public class FileResult {

    @SerializedName("Date")
    public String Date;

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post **FileResult** ?

Comment: FileResult is empty now

Comment: I mean class structure

Comment: Put FileResult.java here

Comment: I added FileResult.java

Comment: Your FileResult.java is not matching with JSON you are getting in result from API. Can you post JSON you are getting from server?

Comment: From Postman for example

Comment: I want to try download file url,url has .png file,it returns like this �����������������������
    ���������������������������������������������������(��������������1���������������2������������������������������i�����������������������Apple��iPhone 6s��������H������������H������13.1.3����2019:11:05 16:04:53����#��������������l��������������t�"���������������'�������������������������0231�������������|����������������������������������������������������������������������
    ������������������������Ē��

Comment: can you add your api response?